# using Bluetooth LE from win32

Tags: winapi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a way to use bluetooth LE from Win32? I can not find a single example nor proper documentation on how to use those BLE functions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-low-energy-functions

What I am trying to achieve is, to emulate a UART Serial interface over BLE.
I know it would be much easier to use win sockets along with RFCOMM, but I am stuck with BLE.

I'm new to bluetooth programming on Windows, so I'd appreciate any help on how to get started with BLE using win32.

Comment: There are at leat 2 libs that gives you such features: 32feet and Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). About UART over BLE take a look on this: https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v14.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_nus_eval.html

Comment: When promoting libraries it is customary to [disclose affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the library recommendations, but I need to directly use Win32 if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following:-

- [Bleak - Bluetooth Low Energy platform Agnostic Klient](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
- [BLE Command Line Tools for Windows](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/ble-tools-windows-10.html)
- [Windows Bluetooth Low Energy Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE)

Comment: Non of these are related to Win32, but thanks anyway. I guess, I'll use C++/WinRT instead. It seems like the best alternative to go for.